# Retrieving POST data on server

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express

The following code is supposed to send data from client to nodejs server upon button click. Upon submit button click, the route gets called but the data doesn't seem to be getting sent to the server. The question is: How can I send data from client to the server and how to retrieve that data on node js side?

**index.ejs:**

```
<script type = "text/javascript"
            src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type = "text/javascript" language = "javascript">

      $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#myButton").bind('click', function() {

          event.preventDefault();

          var data = $('#myEditText').val();
          $.post('/yolo', {textBoxValue: data}, function(callback) {
            document.write("button clicked calling yolo script");
            alert("yolo");
          });

          alert("Button clicked. This button was bind/onClickListener to Jquery: "+data);
        });
      });

    </script>
    <form id = "myForm" action = "http://localhost:3000/yolo" method="post"> <!--action = "http://127.0.0.1/index.js" is for telling the browser which script file will handle the data from this form upon submission -->
      Enter Url: <input id="myEditText" type="text" name="urlEditText"/>
      <br />
      <br />
      Shortened Url:<%= shortenedUrl %> <!--// shortened url passed from the server -->
      <br />
      <br />
      <button id="myButton" type="button" value="Submit" onclick="fetchData()"> Submit </button>
    </form>
```

**index.js:**

```
router.post('/yolo', function(req, res, next) {

    req.on('textBoxValue', function(data) {
        console.log("data recieved: "+ data);
    });

    console.log("yolo post called: "+ req.data + " fromBody: "+ req.body.urlEditText);
    res.render('index', { title: 'NewTitle', shortenedUrl: shortenedUrl});
    console.log("hello inside index.js method 1");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For a start, check the browser's console network tab to see what gets sent: it is probably url-form-encoded, which is not what you want. You can make jQuery to send it as JSON using:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: '/yolo',
  data: JSON.stringify({textBoxValue: data}),
  contentType: 'applicatio/json'
})
```

Then make sure you use a body parser in the server-side ([ref](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.body)), e.g. the [body-parser](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser):

> **req.body**
>
> Contains key-value pairs of data submitted in the request body. By default, it is undefined, and is populated when you use body-parsing middleware[...]

Code would be:

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var jsonParser = bodyParser.json();

router.post('/yolo', jsonParser, function(req, res, next) {
    // here req.body should be the object {textBoxValue: data}
});
```

Comment: I am using body-parser as middleware in app.js. The data gets submitted when I call `$(#myform).submit()` and is available in req.body.urlEditText. However if I just send data by `$.post(/yolo', {textBox:data}, function(){alert("sent")})`, the data isn''t available in req.body.urlEditText

Comment: The posted thing does not have a member `urlEditText`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all: req and res objects are streams in node.js and express/koa.
Nice stuff about streams: https://github.com/substack/stream-handbook

So, u need to "parse"  your data first with something like body-parser.
Then in req object u will find post data in `req.body.{key: value, keyn: valuen}`

Also `textBoxValue` event will newer fired because there are no such event in writable stream. But u always could create event emitters and fire very own events.